# Reusing/overwriting the same variable name for mysqli_query?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am using **$sqlCommand** variable name to validate my user access

`$sqlCommand = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT......`

then I have another **$sqlCommandProductList** variable to check for my existing product list.

`$sqlCommandProductList = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT......`

and I also have **$sqlCommandMostPopular** and **$sqlCommandLatestProducts**....

My question is is it possible to reuse the same variable name **$sqlCommand** throughout the page instead of creating so many variable name for sql query that only used once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can keep using it like this:

```
$sqlCommand = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name......");
...
// after the using is finished, just unset($sqlCommand)
unset($sqlCommand);
// define $sqlCommand again
$sqlCommand = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT password......");
```

But do recommend another **Strategy**, it can be like this:

- **extract** the ''database access process''(db process) into a independent method
- **return**  the info needed from the db process result
- give the info a **understanable** name

like following:

```
function getName($conn, $sql) {
    $sqlCommand = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name......");
    ...
    // this is really needed
    $name = ...;
    return $name;
}

$name = getName($conn, $sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure is this possible.
As long you are sure you do not loose or overwrite data you still need for furhter processing.